# Easier way to add methods to jQuery objects than .data()?

Tags: jquery

I want to add a custom method to a specific jQuery object:

```
$('#DOMelement').customFunc(param); // not a reality
```

Currently, I have:

```
var customFunc = function(param) { 
    // do something special
}
$('#DOMelement').data('customFunc', customFunc);
```

Which I then call, like:

```
var cF = $('#DOMelement').data('customFunc');
cF(param);
```

All of this works, but it's a pain. Is there a better solution? Other than writing an extensive plugin?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function doesn't seem to be related to any particular element, so why not just store it in some global namespace.

If you don't want to create another, you could borrow jQuery's if you're careful not to overwrite anything:

```
jQuery.cF = function(param) {
    // do something special
};

$.cF(param);
```

Comment: how would I set it up to be related to a particular element?

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like  think what you want to do is make a **plugin**. It's not really extensive at all. Taken from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring, you can just do:

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

        // Do your awesome plugin stuff here

    };
})( jQuery );
```

Then calling it is simple:

```
$('#DOMelement').myPlugin();
```

I don't believe you should be putting custom functions in the "data" property. The data property was built with the intention of *embedding custom non-visible data to your HTML*. While I guess you could put functions in there, I'm not sure that's compliant. Also, all of your JavaScript code will then be embedded in your HTML element.

(Taken from http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes)

> Authors can include data for inline client-side scripts or server-side site-wide scripts to process using the data-*="" attributes. These are guaranteed to never be touched by browsers, and allow scripts to include data on HTML elements that scripts can then look for and process.

Here's another article on using `data`: http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/html5_data-_attributes_are_great_and_you_know_it.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend).

In your particular case you would be extending `$` so you might as well just do it patrick's way as long as your careful not to override and existing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$.fn.call = function(){};`

Then create a function for a specific element:

`$('#some_id .some-class').call.myCustomFunction = function(arg1,arg2){
...
};`

Now when you want to call it:

`$('#some_id .some-class').call.myCustomFunction('a','b');`